# Neo4j HA (2.0-Snapshot), Timeout waiting for cluster to elect master

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I have a very simple Neo4j HA setup with a single master instance and an embedded HA instance, which I want to use for batch data loads. Here's the master instance configuration (the one I launch "normally", as a windows service):

```
node_auto_indexing=true
node_keys_indexable=key,entity,annotation
relationship_auto_indexing=true
relationship_keys_indexable=key, weight, label
keep_logical_logs=true
online_backup_enabled=true

ha.server_id=1
ha.initial_hosts=:5001
ha.server=0.0.0.0:6001
ha.cluster_server=:5001
ha.pull_interval=10
ha.tx_push_factor=0
ha.tx_push_strategy=fixed

cypher_parser_version=2.0
remote_shell_enabled=true
remote_shell_port=1377

org.neo4j.server.database.mode=HA
```

I want to be able to start and stop the embedded one on demand. So here's the configuration I load in the Java application:

```
node_auto_indexing=true
node_keys_indexable=key,annotation
relationship_auto_indexing=true
relationship_keys_indexable=key, weight, label
keep_logical_logs=true

org.neo4j.server.database.mode=HA
ha.server_id=2
ha.slave_only=true

ha.initial_hosts=:5001
ha.server=:6002
ha.cluster_server=:5002

ha.pull_interval=10
cypher_parser_version=2.0
```

The idea is to be able to launch the first (windows service) instance as a single / stand-alone node and start the batch loader when needed.

**The problem**

I can launch the windows service successfully and fire queries as usual. When I start my application, it connects just fine and takes the role of a slave node. I can load my data without problems and the master node seems to be in sync, working fine. Now, if the Java application crashes for any reason or finishes and shuts down, the master instance stops working and for any Cypher query returns the following trace:

```
TransactionFailureException
Timeout waiting for cluster to elect master
StackTrace:
org.neo4j.kernel.ha.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.beginTx(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.java:207)
org.neo4j.kernel.TransactionBuilderImpl.begin(TransactionBuilderImpl.java:39)
org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.beginTx(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:882)
org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.prepare(ExecutionEngine.scala:102)
org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:70)
org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:85)
org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.java:80)
org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CypherService.cypher(CypherService.java:95)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)
```

Did I do anything wrong in my configuration?

Btw.: If I restart the second instance, the master instance goes back to "normal".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. As far as the cluster is concerned there are two instances in the cluster, and if one is down there is no quorum, and so it becomes unavailable for safety reasons. In your setup, the way around this is to start a separate arbiter on the master instance so that there will always be 2 out of 3 instances available, and hence the cluster is considered up.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So the minimum for any HA set-up are two nodes, which have to be up all the time..

Comment: @rickard-berg Can you put some guidance how can I start arbiter instance ? I went through official docs as well, but could not able to manage above as answered.